# How to count How many digits have appeared in the columns?

Tags: r

How to create a function that takes an argument - the name of the group of variables P_1, P_2, P_3 or P_4 (from CSV file) - and determines for each variable of the given group a set of counts of values?

Example result for a call to count("P_1"):

```
## $P_1_1
## 
##   1   2   3   4   5   6   7 
##  89  32 508 142  15 281  36 
## 
## $P_1_2
## 
##   1   2   3   4   5   6 
## 261  26 497 251  18  50 
## 
## $P_1_3
## 
##   1   2   3   4   5   6   7 
## 114  26 308 443  77 126   9 
## 
## $P_1_4
## 
##   1   2   3   4   5   6   7 
## 267  21 118 205 202 208  82 
## 
## $P_1_5
## 
##   1   2   3   4   5   6   7 
## 144  46 282 387  33 154  57 
## 
## $P_1_6
## 
##   1   2   3   4   5   6   7 
## 154  21 601 115  19 150  43
```

Part of the CSV file

```
Lp.;P_1_1;P_1_2;P_1_3;P_1_4;P_1_5;P_1_6;P_2_1;P_2_2;P_3_1;P_3_2;P_4_1;P_4_2;P_4_3;P_4_4
1;3;4;4;4;3;3;1;7;7;7;1;3;5;7
2;3;1;1;5;3;3;1;4;6;4;1;5;3;4
3;3;2;3;4;2;7;1;6;6;6;5;3;4;4
4;3;3;4;4;3;4;1;5;6;6;3;3;5;5
5;3;1;4;7;3;3;3;6;5;7;5;5;2;2
6;3;4;1;4;3;3;1;6;7;7;7;4;7;5
7;3;1;1;5;3;7;1;4;6;6;4;1;6;1
8;3;4;6;1;1;1;1;3;6;6;5;1;2;3
9;3;4;4;4;3;3;1;5;6;6;5;3;5;4
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

map(df, table)

#> $Lp.
#> 
#> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
#> 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
#> 
#> $P_1_1
#> 
#> 3 
#> 9 
#> 
#> $P_1_2
#> 
#> 1 2 3 4 
#> 3 1 1 4 
#> 
#> $P_1_3
#> 
#> 1 3 4 6 
#> 3 1 4 1 
#> 
#> $P_1_4
#> 
#> 1 4 5 7 
#> 1 5 2 1 
#> 
#> $P_1_5
#> 
#> 1 2 3 
#> 1 1 7 
#> 
#> $P_1_6
#> 
#> 1 3 4 7 
#> 1 5 1 2 
#> 
#> $P_2_1
#> 
#> 1 3 
#> 8 1 
#> 
#> $P_2_2
#> 
#> 3 4 5 6 7 
#> 1 2 2 3 1 
#> 
#> $P_3_1
#> 
#> 5 6 7 
#> 1 6 2 
#> 
#> $P_3_2
#> 
#> 4 6 7 
#> 1 5 3 
#> 
#> $P_4_1
#> 
#> 1 3 4 5 7 
#> 2 1 1 4 1 
#> 
#> $P_4_2
#> 
#> 1 3 4 5 
#> 2 4 1 2 
#> 
#> $P_4_3
#> 
#> 2 3 4 5 6 7 
#> 2 1 1 3 1 1 
#> 
#> $P_4_4
#> 
#> 1 2 3 4 5 7 
#> 1 1 1 3 2 1
```